# jmenu not transferring focus properly on mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, applet, focus, jmenu

I have a web applet that uses a JMenuBar. On Windows everything works great, but OS X is a different story. For some reason the JMenus are not properly transferring focus to their children using the OS X safari combo. Sub-menus and items should highlight on mouse hover but do not. When the user presses the the JMenu and leaves the mouse pressed as they navigate through the sub-menus everything highlights as it should. I also noticed that this only happens to JMenus that are embedded in the applet's content pane. If the applet generates a separate JFrame window with a JMenu, then focus is passed correctly. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.